# Bro's password... must've forgotten

Tags: cipher, knowledge, language, password

My overseas friend has forgotten the password to his SackExpunge account, and the only information he wrote down about it was this:

> Username: LiveSound
>
> Password: `rupn4u818n0`

However, the password he wrote down turned out to be invalid. Can you help him figure out what his actual password is?

---

**HINT 1:**

> My friend is Taiwanese.

**HINT 2:**

> Added a relevant tag.

**HINT 3:**

> The username and the title contain some relevant information. Make sure you transcribe them properly!

**HINT 4:**

> There are some spaces missing in the "password."

Comment: Considering your first hint, are the numbers suppose to represent letters that sound similar? In Taiwan, the language spoken is somewhat similar to Hokkien, and 4 is pronounced 'si', or 'C', 8 would be 'peh', or 'P', and 1 would be 'yi' or 'E'. I'm not sure about 0 though.

Comment: @Arch2K your assumption that Taiwanese language is involved here is right! However, the process is a bit more involved than simply replacing numbers with letters. The final answer should look more recognizable than it is currently now.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is that your friend wrote down

> the latin letters that appear on the keys he hits, except he uses a two-language keyboard such as the one below. Therefore the Taiwanese characters would be 
> $$ㄐㄧㄣㄙ'ㄧㄚㄅㄚㄙㄢ$$
> but I don't know what that means, online translators fails at interpreting this. 
>  It reads $$chins'iapanan\qquad \text{ (China/Japan?)}$$
>  which doesn't ring a bell either.
>  Of course each key also features different kanji, but that makes too many possibilities without the help from a reliable translator.
>  [image]

Comment: You're on the right track! I added a couple more hints to help you out :)